# Firebase update or add value when item has a key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I didnt find anything clever to get the solution yet.

This is my database:

[image]

```
var songKey = firebase.database().ref('songs').push().key;

                var songData = {
                  artist: finalSongTitle,
                  songTitle: songTitle,
                  genre: genre,
                  songImage: dlUrl,
                  user: user.uid,
                  isApproved: false,
                  songUrl: 'url'
                };

var updates = {};
    updates['songs/' + songKey] = songData;
    firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
```

Now i want to update or set the `songUrl` but I'm not able to pass the key I set before. So how can I change the value?

This is when I set the data first time. Now like you guys said if I have to save the key, I saved it in a var and when I want to add the songUrl im using this:

```
    var secretKey = updates;

var songData2 = {
                  songUrl: songUrl
                };

var updates2 = {};
updates2[secretKey] = songData2;
firebase.database().ref().update(updates2);
```

But then I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Reference.update failed: First argument contains an invalid key ([object Object]) in path /[object Object]. Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"
```

Comment: If you can't build a path to the node to update, then you won't be able to update it.  You will have to remember that child key string in order to do so.

Comment: @DougStevenson okay I understand, I followed your approach and saved they key, console log shows it to me but im getting this error. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured out the solution. For everyone who is interested, I saved the key in a var and updated the single value with this line of code:

```
firebase.database().ref('songs/' + secretKey).update({ songUrl: songUrl });
```

For anybody who is asking why I can't do it in one step: in my use case I'm uploading files step by step and I have to insert the data in a queue.